# Can I use straight SQL in Django models?

Tags: sql, django

And, if I can, does that mean I lose my advantage of treating the results as objects?  I find complex queries confusing in many ORMs, not just Django's.  But, it is probably because I have never really used an ORM.  Does anyone use straight up SQL anymore?

edit:  Am I defeating the purpose of having a framework if I bypass the ORM completely? They all have a "nifty" ORM, but when it comes to queries with lots of subqueries, derived tables, it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: "Does anyone use straight up SQL anymore?" - Yes.

Comment: I use straight up SQL all the time. Once you learn how the ORM generates the SQL, much of the battle is won. Use the debug toolbar or sql logs to see the sausage being made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Django's [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) you have different possibilities:

- You can use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) which will return a queryset which evaluates to model objects. Therefore it is, as the name says, somehow limited, because for returning *model instances* it is necessary to eg. query the model's table. But you have the possibility to add additional SQL eg. the `WHERE` or `ORDER` clause. Querysets that use `extra()` can still use the features of the ORM - like chaining multiple `filter()` for example.
- [`raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#raw) returns a `RawQueryset` which also can be iterated over to get model instances, but you loose a lot of features that the ORM would normally provide.
- And of course you can execute SQL directly, using a [low level connection cursor API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) (no model instances of course).

Study [the documentation on raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), there's also a lot of information on eg. how to map a model's fields on the data coming from a raw query and documeting a few gotchas when passing parameters into the query.

To also answer your edited question: I wouldn't use raw SQL when you can do it with the ORM, but of course the ORM is limited and if you need to do some more complex stuff you will always have to switch to SQL (but sometimes using `extra()` is enough-so you can still use the advantages of the ORM). Don't forget that the ORM works with every DB backend, while the  custom SQL might not work with every database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw SQL to either [return objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries); or if you want you can [bypass the ORM completely](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).